# Running Nuxt.js app on IE 11 throws an error

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to test my Nuxt.js app on IE 11 but it's stuck on the loading page and throws the error below.
[image: Syntax error]
I'm using Nuxt.js v2.10.2 and running on spa mode.

**EDIT**

Below is the line where the syntax error fires.
[image: Syntax error line]
And I discovered that three.js is causing this (I use a particle system script).

Comment: could you please show us the error line?

Comment: @Ifaruki I've updated my question above (included the line that causes the error)

Comment: maybe some polyfill is missing... you can add some polyfills into your app by putting this script in the head `<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Ces2018%2Ces5%2Ces6%2Ces7"></script>`

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Comment: @dunli Are you able to resolve this issue? I am also stuck at this place